# Avoid altering page with Jquery with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a page set up with multiple rows. Each row has two columns. The second column is hidden until a button is clicked, and then it is revealed with Jquery. The problem is that when it appears, it moves the whole page down. I've tried using position:absolute, but then it gets put on top of the first column. I need to avoid using any sort of "left, right, etc" modifiers because I need this to render properly on differently sized screens. How do I get it to appear in its proper place?

The code I have is:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div id="event" class="span8" onclick="preview({{ name.event_id }})">
     <strong>
    {{ name.title|truncatechars:50 }}
     </strong> <br>
    Location: {{ name.location|truncatechars:50 }} <br>
    Start Date: {{ name.start|truncatechars:50 }} <br>
    End Date: {{ name.end|truncatechars:50 }} 
    <a onClick="event.stopPropagation()" class="page btn btn-primary btn-small" href="/eventsearch/eventsearch/event/{{ name.event_id }}">Event Page</a>
  </div>
  <div id="block{{ name.event_id }}" class="span4 block">{{ name.title }} </div>
</div>
```

the first column is supposed to be #event and the second is #block

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the target pseudo class for this.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/XuJ83/3/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col1">Col1
    <a class="showCol" href="#row1">Show Col2</a>
  </div>
  <div id="row1" class="col col2">Col2</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.row
{
    clear:both;
}
.col
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.col1
{
    background: orange;
}
.col2
{
    display:none;
    background: green;
}
.col2:target
{
    display:block;
}
.showCol
{
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite it, because in your example you have equally sized columns. My right column is larger than the left, which is what causes the page to shift down when I load it.

Comment: @Xonal I updated the fiddle so the the right col is larger

Comment: Bah, I'm sorry, I'm being really unclear. Larger in terms of height.

Comment: @Xonal I updated the fiddle so the the right col is higher